# Solving Independent Set through Vertex Cover

Tags: algorithms, vertex-cover

I have an Independent Set problem, in which I have to check if given graph has a IS of given size $k$. I've already written a Vertex Cover algorithm a while back and I hope I can reuse it here. Those algorithms are closely related, since if graph $G = (V, E)$ has IS of size $k$ iff it has VC of size $V - k$. So am I right that I can I just use my VC algorithm with $k' = V - k$?

I've read [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11904/reduction-from-vertex-cover-to-an-independent-set-problem) and [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/87067/how-is-vertex-cover-reducable-to-independent-set-using-parametrized-reduction-wi) question and after that I've started doubting that this is that simple.

Comment: Seems like you have answered yourself...

Comment: @Steven I've read https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11904/reduction-from-vertex-cover-to-an-independent-set-problem and https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/87067/how-is-vertex-cover-reducable-to-independent-set-using-parametrized-reduction-wi and after that I've started doubting that this is that simple.

Comment: @Steven thank you, I just got confused here! Please post an answer, I'll accept it right away.

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your question to add a bit of context, since simple yes/no questions are discouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is that simple, those questions are talking about fixed parameter tractable algorithms w.r.t. the size $k$ of an independent set/vertex cover. Your algorithm will work just fine setting $k' = |V| - k$. Clearly, the new value $k'$ also affects the running time of your algorithm.